# OSX Terminal Mail Attachment as body

Tags: macos, email, terminal, attachment, uuencode

I am trying to send an attachment which I created as mail body, but don't find any solution.

Here is my code,

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" > textfile.txt
uuencode /Users/bariscaliskan/Desktop/testfold/textfile.txt file.txt | mail -s "mailing test" testmail@mail.com
```

This sends the file as attachment but I want that text to be in mail body.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | mail -s "mailing test" test@test.com
```